# Adding fade-in to javascript timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html body I am using a javascript that writes and changes a line of text in my div, with ID "moto", every 5 seconds.

```js
    var text = ["TEXT 1","TEXT 2","TEXT 3","TEXT 4"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("moto");
    ChangeFunction();
    setInterval(ChangeFunction, 5000);
    
    function ChangeFunction() {
        elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
    }
```

```css
    #moto{
      -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<div id="moto"></div>
```

Do I need to apply some java fade-in fade-out? I would rather use CSS...

Comment: You will have to write a css class with fade-in and fadeOut styles and then toggle these classes on the element In the interval ..

Comment: Yes you will need to use Javascript for this. If you simply change `innerHTML` there's nothing to fade. You first fade out the _oldtext_, then put the _newtext_ in, then fade it in. (note: Javascript has nothing to do with Java despite the name similarity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to do this easily as below

```js
var text = ["TEXT 1","TEXT 2","TEXT 3","TEXT 4"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("moto");
ChangeFunction();
setInterval(ChangeFunction, 5000);

function ChangeFunction() {
    var moto = text[counter++];
    $(elem).fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(elem).html(moto);
      $(elem).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moto"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on my PC. Do JQuerry need to be installed first in order for my PC to work with this code?

Comment: @71GA, you can link the jquery from the CDN as I mentioned above. Just place the script tag inside `<head></head>`

Comment: Otherwise, you can download it locally and refer to the local version

Comment: One more question. On page load text is nonexistent for some time and it then starts to render. When this happens the entire page below the text is moved downwards. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: It's because, the method `ChangeFunction();` is called on the page load. You can remove this and just keep the `setInterval(ChangeFunction, 5000);` there only.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript at all. Here's a pure CSS implementation:

```css
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
#moto {
  position: relative;
}
#moto div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade 4s 0s infinite alternate-reverse;
}
#moto :nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
}
#moto :nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
#moto :nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
#moto :nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="moto">
  <div>TEXT 1</div>
  <div>TEXT 2</div>
  <div>TEXT 3</div>
  <div>TEXT 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This assumes pre-exiting markup, which according to OP is not there (they are setting `innerHTML`). But neat trick the negative delay!

Comment: @tmslnz If there's no pre-existing markup, the CSS can be generated using JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, but then it would be a bit of a _roundabout_ way to go at it, wouldn't it?

Comment: @tmslnz Maybe it would be a bit more complicated, but the performance would be better than when changing `innerHTML`.

Comment: If the extra code complexity it is worth the few _microseconds_ gained for one bit of text… but yes technically you are right.

Comment: What does the **4s** and **0s** in this line **animation: fade 4s 0s infinite alternate-reverse;** mean?

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I figured out that using javascript is the way to go here. It is just more readable.

Comment: @71GA 4s is the [duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration) of the animation, and 0s is the [delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay).